# SQL server 2008 cannot change table name

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I created a table in SQL server 2008 and saved it. But when I try to amend the column definitions on the table via SSMS it won't let me.

How can I modify the table structure via SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools->Options`

Form `Options`-> select `Designers`: Here Uncheck the option: `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The **Save** (Not Permitted) dialog box warns you that saving changes
>   is not permitted because the changes you have made require the listed
>   tables to be dropped and re-created.
>
> The following actions might require a table to be re-created:
>
> - Adding a new column to the middle of the table
> - Dropping a column
> - Changing column nullability
> - Changing the order of the columns
> - Changing the data type of a column
>
> To change this option, on the **Tools** menu, click **Options**,
>   expand **Designers**, and then click T**able and Database Designers**.
>   Select or clear the **Prevent saving changes that require the table to
>   be re-created check box**.

[MSDN Source article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx)

Comment: Please don't post answers that are just links. See my edit for an example of how you should answer questions here. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify it via management studio but you should be able to do it via sql ALTER TABLE.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD NewColumn INT


ALTER TABLE myTable 
DROP COLUMN MyColumn
```

Comment: You can modify your tables within SSMS. You just need to amend your preferences.

Comment: Ah ok. Ill tick that off as my thing learned for the day. :)